# How to change the images displayed when my Kindle Touch is put to sleep?

Tags: kindle, image

Whenever I press the power button on my Kindle Touch, an image is displayed on the e-ink screen. The images depict various typographical tools and elements (like a typewriter, etc.).

However, it would be nice to use my own images in their place. Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

This is possible. However, you must jailbreak your Kindle first. Basically you:

1. [Jailbreak](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_Touch_Hacking#Jailbreak) the Kindle.
2. Load the [screensaver hack](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kindle_Touch_Hacking#Screen_Savers) to your Kindle.
3. Copy the images to your Kindle. [This site](http://www.epubor.com/7-places-to-download-kindle-screensavers.html) has a list of places to get these.